# How to mark two different locations in two maps is same page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

One marker works great.I added a second marker but it does not appear.

where is the error in my code? I'm sure it's simple but it's not working.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
       var mapOptions = {
               zoom: 15,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.99379, -38.52661),  
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
           };
       var mapOptions2 = {
               zoom: 15,
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.994898, -38.470841),  
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
           };

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-canvas'),
                                       mapOptions);
       var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location-canvas2'),
                                       mapOptions2);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       map: map,
                       draggable: false,
                       position: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.99379, -38.52661)
           });

       var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                       map: map,
                       draggable: false,
                       position: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.994898, -38.470841)
           });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', initialize);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

**html**

```
<div id='location-canvas' style='width:100%;height:200px;'></div> 
<div id='location-canvas2' style='width:100%;height:200px;'></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't appear where? You are putting it on the first map, not on map2.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting both markers on "map", which is centered such that marker2 isn't in view.  Change the definition of marker2 to:

```
   var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: map2,
                   draggable: false,
                   position: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.994898, -38.470841)
       });
```